# Get value from codenameone OnOff switch

Tags: java, codenameone

How can I get a value from the codenameone OnOff switch state. I have searched all over the internet and I cant find an example.I want to know when its on or off. Please help. I have tried this and many other combinations but I have not got a way yet. I have also read through codename one developers manual, there is no guidance on that.

```
protected void onMain_AccidentCoverAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {

   String state = findAccidentCover(c).getOn();

   Dialog.show("State", state, "OK", null);

}
```

I have also tried

```
protected void onMain_AccidentCoverAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {

   String state = findAccidentCover(c).getComponentState().toString();

   Dialog.show("State", state, "OK", null);

}
```

Comment: Rather then searching you should try to code and if strucked paste the code and we would be more then happy to help

Comment: I have tried many combinations but they all never seemed to work, so din't really see the point of writing a lot of code that doesn't work anyway to prove my point...that I need help at this point. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: I see your comment in reply to my question, so I think what is missing is a description of exactly why things didn't work - didn't compile, crashed, always returned `false`, or what? Does `findAccidentCover` actually return the correct `OnOffSwitch`?

Comment: I just need the switch to trigger an action when I either switch it on or off. That's all I need/am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Googling, I [found this page](https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/javadoc/com/codename1/components/OnOffSwitch.html#isValue()), so it would appear your solution might be:

```
protected void onMain_AccidentCoverAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
   boolean state = findAccidentCover(c).isValue();

   Dialog.show("State", state ? "On" : "Off", "OK", null);
}
```

As an aside, `isValue()` is a terrible name for the method.

Comment: Thanks for the try, I had visited that page and also tried that option, it dint work and still hasn't worked.

Comment: Sorry about the name, I thought about isSelected and decided it might not fit all use cases and isOn/Off doesn't either.

Comment: Well in using this method the value of the boolean state can be picked in another even trigger that is checking on the switch state. I wanted the switching to trigger an event when flicked.

Comment: Use addActionListener